# rendering negative frame ranges. How to?

Tags: rendering

Moving keyframes isn't an option here. I am working with files from other packages and need the data transfer to be consistent across all platforms.

Basically I have an animation that starts at 0 but need an establishing shot to start at -60

I can preview from -60 just cant render from -60

Comment: That is a known limitation. Unfortunately there is no solution other than moving the keyframes to positive frames in the dope sheet.

Answer (score -1):

In 2.8 there is an option to do this in the blender properties window.

Comment: Do you mean the option *Allow Negative Frames* in the *Animation* section in the *Preferences*? No, it does not work for rendering the animation.  While you can play the animation including negative keyframes in the viewport, rendering still can't start with a frame before zero.